# Expandable row in material table , all rows expanded when using in mat-tab on switching tab

Tags: angular-material

I have a table while using in mat-tab , expandable row are getting expanded on switching tabs

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yjgkst
here is the link

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mat expansion panel is not working properly in mat tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50463584/mat-expansion-panel-is-not-working-properly-in-mat-tab)

Comment: There is also an open [github issue](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/5269). Workaround can be found in both duplicate and github urls.

Answer (score 6):

Use `<ng-template matTabContent>` in the `<mat-tab>`

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yeveze?file=src/app/table-expandable-rows-example.html)

Comment: Can you explain why this is working please?

Comment: This is described in the documentation and it works

Answer (score 0):

Use `<ng-template matTabContent>` in the `<mat-tab>` this is a solution, that changes the behaviour of each tab, with this template it lazy loads each tab, and whenever you click the tab, it does trigger ngOnInit...
I wanted to keep the behaviour I have, I just wanted to remove the bug of expanding rows whenever I click another tab..

It worked for me! :)
You can just wrap up your element (which has the table) with a **div**, e.g.:

```
 <mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="start">
  <mat-tab label="First"><div><app-table-element-selector></app-table-element-selector></div></mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"><app-element2-selector></app-element2-selector></mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third"><app-element3-selector></app-element3-selector></mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```